# Can I create a filesystem object of a specific directory?

Tags: python, kivy, filesystemobject, object-property

Need to create this type of object (from kivy.properties & Kivy filechooser)

`ObjectProperty(FileSystemLocal(), baseclass=FileSystemAbstract)`

Comment: i think the best option is to import os and use bash commands

Comment: Not sure I understand how to use it for this need, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The `FileSystemLocal` class is a simple interface to some `os` and `os.path` methods. For example, the `listdir()` method of `FileSystemLocal` is simply a call to `os.listdir()`. So it is not specific to any directory, it is just specific to the local `os` and `os.path`. So, technically, the answer is no.

Perhaps you could define your own `FileSystemLocal` subclass that meets your requirements.

Here is an example of an extension of `FileSystemLocal` that uses a specific directory:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import (basename, join, getsize, isdir)

from sys import platform as core_platform

from kivy import Logger
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileSystemAbstract, _have_win32file

platform = core_platform

_have_win32file = False
if platform == 'win':
    # Import that module here as it's not available on non-windows machines.
    try:
        from win32file import FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, GetFileAttributesExW, \
                              error
        _have_win32file = True
    except ImportError:
        Logger.error('filechooser: win32file module is missing')
        Logger.error('filechooser: we cant check if a file is hidden or not')


class FileSystemLocalDir(FileSystemAbstract):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dir = kwargs.pop('dir', None)
        super(FileSystemLocalDir, self).__init__()

    def listdir(self, fn):
        if self.dir is not None:
            fn = join(self.dir, fn)
        print('listdir for', fn)
        return listdir(fn)

    def getsize(self, fn):
        if self.dir is not None:
            fn = join(self.dir, fn)
        return getsize(fn)

    def is_hidden(self, fn):
        if self.dir is not None:
            fn = join(self.dir, fn)
        if platform == 'win':
            if not _have_win32file:
                return False
            try:
                return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
            except error:
                # This error can occurred when a file is already accessed by
                # someone else. So don't return to True, because we have lot
                # of chances to not being able to do anything with it.
                Logger.exception('unable to access to <%s>' % fn)
                return True

        return basename(fn).startswith('.')

    def is_dir(self, fn):
        if self.dir is not None:
            fn = join(self.dir, fn)
        return isdir(fn)
```

This can be used as:

```
fsld = FileSystemLocalDir(dir='/home')
print('dir:', fsld.dir)
print('listdir .:', fsld.listdir('.'))
print('listdir freddy:', fsld.listdir('freddy'))  # lists home directory of user `freddy`
print('listdir /usr:', fsld.listdir('/usr')) # this will list /usr regardless of the setting for self.dir
```

Note:

- The `FileSystemLocalDir` is based heavily on `FileSystemLocal`.
- The `dir=` in the constructor sets the default directory that is consulted for all the methods of `FileSystemLocalDir`.
- If the `dir=` argument is not provided, the `FileSystemLocalDir` is equivalent to `FileSystemLocal`.
- If an argument to any method of `FileSystemLocalDir` begins with a `/`, it is treated as an absolute path and the provided default directory is ignored (this is an effect of the use of `os.join`).

Comment: I can't use the os.listdir somehow with a specific directory? and That way to define my own FileSystemLocal subclass

Comment: I have added an example to my answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much! will implement it now!
Another question related to this and to the project I'm building, any idea how I send FileSystemLocal Object through a socket?

Comment: Not sure how you could send it through a socket. But keep in mind that the `FileSystemLocal` is based on the `os` library of python, so no matter where the `FileSystemLocal` is created, it will only provide information about the file system where it is located. If you create it on computer `A` and use it on computer `A`, it will tell you about the files on computer `A`. If you were able to send that `FileSystemLocal` through a socket to computer `B` and run it on computer `B`, it will only tell you about the files on computer `B`.

Comment: I meant creating this object: ObjectProperty(FileSystemLocal(), baseclass=FileSystemAbstract)
and then to send it, that way it will display computer A on computer B.
Will it work that way? and if yes so any idea how to send it?

Comment: No, it won't work that way. It will display computer A on computer A, and computer B on computer B.